# Using JS executor to enter text to a xpath element

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, executor

I am using selenium and i need to write to and xpath element
so far i managed to successfully make a click on it 
by using this

```
driver.findElement(
     By.xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Vehicle:'])[1]/following::ul[1]"))
     .click();
```

Then i need to write on it, i've been using this

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//*[normalize space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Vehicle:'])[1]/following::ul[1]"));

     ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].value='SED'",ele);
```

In the example i tried to write `SED` but i can't it to enter any text

Comment: I believe you are pointing to the wrong node. How can you send value to `ul`? Is there a text field with in `ul`? Can you post the html of the `ul` with its children.

Comment: `<ul class="select2-choices">  <li class="select2-search-field">    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitilize="off" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input" id="s2id_autogen8" tabindex="2" style="width: 10px;">  </li></ul>` @supputuri

Comment: `ul.select2-choices input.select2-input` is the css that you can use. If you want to use the xpath then `//ul[@class='select2-choices']//input[@class='select2-input']`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have identified your element correctly and you have used `.click()` on to get inside the textbox, you can use `sendKeys()` to enter the value ("SED") in it. In this case you do not need to create a `JavascriptExecutor` instance

Example:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//*[normalize space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Vehicle:'])[1]/following::ul[1]")).sendKeys("SED");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer 
I already tried that but it sends me this error `error":"element not interactable","message":"Element <ul class=\"select2-choices\"> is not reachable by keyboard"`

Comment: `ul` is not an input tag. You are definitely pointing to a wrong element.